# How much overlap is there between knowledge of Spring and Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Why would a job candidate say he "knows Spring MVC well but Spring not so well"?

The implication that you can, in fact, know Spring MVC without Spring is a surprising one to me because I thought knowledge of Spring was a prerequisite for working with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC can be made to work using convention-over-configuration to a very large degree. You can write entire applications with little in the way of configuration, if you choose to do so.

This candidate may have been able to write Spring MVC apps with little knowledge of how it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps knowing Spring means a lot more... For example Spring Security, Spring Batch, Spring Integration, Spring ...oh my god there are so many modules more to go...

I would reject to say I know Spring, too, and I'm working a lot with it in many areas...